# Rails: Dynamically Generating form elements for a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I have a model, `Lesson`, which `has_many :lesson_objectives`. Each `Lesson` can have an unlimited number of `LessonObjectives` - which is where part of the problem comes in.

I am planning to integrate the controllers/views for these two models together - such that whenever somebody wants to create a `Lesson` they will also have to provide all of the `LessonObjective`s for it. I would like a solution whereby the user is presented with maybe two fields by default, for example, "Objecive 1" and "Objective 2" , and then any subsequent fields get added on the fly as the user types. When the user fills in "Objective n" then a field for "Objective n+1" will appear automatically.

However I'm unsure about two things.

- The best way to add this behaviour into the views. It will probably require a lot of jQuery and I'm not sure about the best practices. For example, what if a user deletes "Objecive 5" and then "Objective 6" would have to be shuffled up to fill "Objective 5"?
- How the form fields can be configured (names, ids) so that Rails will understand the behaviour and be able to save the data without breaking the rails conventions and keeping it RESTful and DRY.

If a gem might help then feel free to suggest it! I've been using SimpleForm and a few others.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you'll need to delve into JQuery to get the automatic creation of new LessonObjective input fields once the default lessonObjective2 is entered.

> For example, what if a user deletes "Objecive 5" and then "Objective 6" would have to be shuffled up to fill "Objective 5"?

Best practices dictates that wouldn't involve JQuery,  but would involve a PARTIAL! and AJAX.

That's the key,  whatever creates the display of the all current lessonObjectives would be in a partial.  That partial would be responsible for numbering the objectives in sequence.

Then if you have a 'delete' link (remote=>true), and hit a controller action that deletes a lessonObjective,  that controller would render javascript that causes the partial to be re-rendered,  this time with a new list of all lessonObjectives (minus the one you just deleted).

simple_form is fine,  plain old rails form helpers would work fine.  Nothing about what you are intending impacts your choice of form technology.

> How the form fields can be configured (names, ids) so that Rails will understand the behaviour and be able to save the data without breaking the rails conventions and keeping it RESTful and DRY.

Just remember the basics of how the rails helpers name inputs:

If your form is foo,  and an input within that form is bar,  it's name is 'foo[bar]'

You can do everything you want with just plain old rails out of the box.  The hardest part will be the jquery to add the new input fields with the proper names so they'll post correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it has cleared a lot up for me. Would `Lesson[LessonObjective][1]`, `Lesson[LessonObjective][2]` be the form naming convention for the partial fields - so that rails would understand the relationship?

Comment: just make sure the integer values are the actual id values for LessonObjective objects,  the (1,2,3..) sequence is artificial, and created by the view.